How to run multiple maven commands parallely in batch file?
I want to run multiple Selenium/maven projects from cmd using a batch file. I want each project to start execution and open new browser session.
below batch script is not working. Script doesn't start and selenium is not opening any browser sessions and the path of Selenium project in Local repo/folder is correct.
Error Message:
"The system cannot find the path specified."
@echo off
SET DEVELOPMENT_HOME=C:\Eclipse_LocalRepo\Automation

cd %DEVELOPMENT_HOME%\Project1\ 
call mvn test
 
&

cd %DEVELOPMENT_HOME%\Project2\ 
call mvn test


Welcome to the community! Right now, this question isn't answerable. Can you add: any error messages you are getting? Be more descriptive of "script is not working." What does "not working" mean? Doesn't run? Doesn't start Selenium? The more details you can add the better!

You can create a single Powershell script like this:
$DEVELOPMENT_HOME = "C:\Eclipse_LocalRepo\Automation"

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location "$using:DEVELOPMENT_HOME\Project1"
    & mvn test
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location "$using:DEVELOPMENT_HOME\Project2"
    & mvn test
}

# Wait for both to finish
Get-Job | Wait-Job

# Display results
Get-Job | Receive-Job

Or you can create a simpler script that receives the path as argument:
param (
    [string]$ProjectPath
)

Set-Location -Path $ProjectPath
& mvn test

And run it twice, in parallel:
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & .\RunMavenTest.ps1 -ProjectPath "C:\Eclipse_LocalRepo\Automation\Project1" } | Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & .\RunMavenTest.ps1 -ProjectPath "C:\Eclipse_LocalRepo\Automation\Project2" }

